# Initializing jstl variable while using custom tags

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib

I have created my own custom `tag-lib`, like:

```
<mytaglib:render id="feature.render">
```

Above `tag-lib` will use this id `feature.render` and get some `HTML` data.

What I want to do is store the content returned by above id in a `jstl` variable. What I did is:

```
<c:set var="renderContent"> <mytaglib:render id="feature.render"> </c:set>
```

But above solution does not work, variable `renderContent` in null.

When I do above thing by putting `<mytaglib:render id="feature.render">` it separate `jsp` file and include that `jsp` file like

```
<c:set var="renderContent"><jsp:include page="getContent"/></c:set>
```

and `jsp` page `getContent` has:

```
<mytaglib:render id="feature.render">
```

it works.

I dont know why it is not working when done in-line and why it works when put in separate file.

I want to do in same `jsp` file. Any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

I would just add an attribute called `var` to your tag. Use it to set the attribute name to expose your object:

```
<mytaglib:render id="feature.render" var="renderContent"/>
```

In your tag, set your object as an attribute in the page context:

```
pageContext.setAttribute(var, yourObject);
```